# Preprocessing frames before passing to the model for object detection

Tags: image, opencv

I am working on a project to detect objects from video using tensorflow API.
I am new to video analytics and so I would like to know what are the common practices while making the inference.
Do you run the model on every frame or skip frames?
when do you perform background subtraction?
Once you detected the object,how do you stop the model from detecting the same object again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you run the model on every frame or skip frames?**

Depends how long your processing time is. If you can process each frame efficiently enough that you don't start lagging behind on your frame queue, then why not process each frame? This entirely comes down to your application and level of optimization.  I've certainly written both types of vision applications; ones where each frame needs processing, and others where you only process every 1/X frames.

**When do you perform background subtraction?**

Once you have enough data to accurately classify the "background". For example I've had applications where I control the lighting and background and I know that anything that is black is deemed "background". Then I look for the regions that actually have non black pixels. This happens in the first frame. If the objects are stationary it only needs to happen once.. but if the objects are in motion it may need to happen periodically.

If the background isn't a known color/pattern/etc, you'll have to find objects and deem "foreground" vs "background", which would likely happen in the first ~3-5 frames.

**Once you detected the object,how do you stop the model from detecting the same object again?**

Depends. Will there be motion? If everything is stationary, you want "mask" over the region that the object resides in the image. You're ignoring this specific area and only processing around it.  If the objects are in motion / non-stationary, you need to classify every object every frame and **track** each object frame by frame.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for your valuable insights.I want to detect objects from multiple ip camera streams.Most of the answers on google recommends to run a thread for grabbing frames and adding to queue ,then another thread for fetching frames from queue and run the model.Is this the most efficient way to do the processing ? Please advise.

Comment: Note:I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer.Apologies